# Using Math symbols as a dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript

```
BEE = 20;
STACKMENOW = 10;
TYPE = 1; // (1 = ADDITION, 0 = SUBSTRACTION)

NEWVALUE  = BEE (TYPE? + : - ) =STACKMENOW;

console.log(NEWVALUE); // This should be  30 if the TYPE is 1, and 10 if the type is 0, is this possible?
```

See on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3663w4ey/15/

Reason I ask this is because I need to sync players stats with a huge list of properties on my game server and that is if a user is equipping the item. It would be nice to just assign the math symbol to the type variable to determine if it's additive or subtraction. This way I would not need to re-write all the property names and then use the '-=' shorthand. (Or vise versa). If that make sense. I'm horrible at explaining things, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Multiply by `+1` or `-1` as needed. Done. In fact, you can define `TYPE` as `1` for addition, `-1` for subtraction, and just multiply.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Wow, never thought of that. I'll try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just make up syntax. There are several ways you could implement this, but Niet's seems pretty simple.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I was just thinking if it's possible to use `-=` and `+=` inside a variable. I wonder if that's  not possible in any language, or only in JS?

Comment: Some languages implement `+` as a function and play syntactic sugar games to allow uses like this, but JS isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just split *any* code up and spread it over the ternary operator.
Running your code in my browser console gives me:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

It is not entirely clear to me what your goal is, but assuming you want to do

```
NEWVALUE = BEE += STACKMENOW;
```

or the same with `-=`, you can rewrite your statement to use `+=` after `BEE` and `+` or `-` in front of `STACKMENOW`, but inside the ternary operator:

```
NEWVALUE = BEE += TYPE ? STACKMENOW : -STACKMENOW;
```

If you don't want to write `STACKMENOW` twice, you can as well use `1` or `-1` and multiply that with `STACKMENOW` (although I imagine it might be just a little slower):

```
NEWVALUE = BEE += (TYPE ? 1 : -1) * STACKMENOW;
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like the * 1 or -1 would be the way to go. Marked as best.